# Prove that a graph has no more than $n+n^{4/3}$ edges.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> In a graph on $n$ vertices all cycles have length at least $7$. Prove
>   that a graph has no more than $n+n^{4/3}$ edges.

Where do I start?

Comment: Where is this question from? What have you tried?

Comment: @nbubis I can't identify the type of the graph so I don't know what to do. Сould you give me a hint?

Comment: You still haven't stated where the question is from. Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest cycle length is known as the girth of the graph, and it has been shown that an upper bound for the maximum number of edges in a graph with $n$ verticies and girth $g=2k+1$ is actually $^{[1]}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(n+n^{1+1/k}\right)$$
In your case, $g=7, k=3$, so the maximum number of edges is actually half what you stated:
$$\#\text{edges}_{max}=\frac{1}{2}\left(n+n^{4/3}\right)$$

<sup>[1]</sup> Theorem 4.1 of [The history of degenerate (bipartite)
extremal graph problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5167.pdf).

Comment: but my graph is not bipartite